# Unable to access the HardDisk drive in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I recently installed Ubuntu along with Windows 10. It is working perfectly till today. But I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 form **Software Updater** and restarted my system.

After restarting I am getting following Error while opening other disk drives (named 136 GB Volume).

[image]

Please notice that I am able to access these drives(NTFS partitioned) before updating the system but now it is showing error.

Now I am having access to **Computer** drive only (that is EXT4).

Please help me to solve this issue. As I am new to Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you hibernated or suspended your Windows before booting Ubuntu? If so, boot to Windows and shutdown properly.

Comment: No I just Shut down it. And then I reboot with Windows 10 and working there for more then 2 hours. but When I rebooted it Ubuntu again it is showing Error.

Answer (score 14):

Simply open terminal and type this command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
```

you can replace /dev/sda2 by your appropriate drive in which you are facing problem, like in my case there was a same problem with my drive /dev/ada4

Comment: How to know my drive ? , Yup its displaying in error window.

Comment: but not able access windows C drive. mount not permitted.

Comment: on run this over / where I have issue, I got : Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

Comment: Will this erase the content of the disk?

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 (or Windows 8/8.1), by default, hibernates all drives.

In order to access Windows drives from other OSes in dual boot you need to disable the *fastboot* default option in Windows.

1. Option 1

Open Control Panel > Power Options. Click "*Choose what the power buttons do*" and then "*Change settings that are currently unavailable*". Under "*Shutdown settings*", uncheck the Turn on fast startup box, click on the "*Save changes*" button and shutdown (do not simply reboot because it will reverse the changes).

2. Option 2 - Edit the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power` and change its DWORD value to 0. Shutdown.

Source: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Anyway, you **shouldn't** be messing with your Windows system partition from Ubuntu. If you need to share files between OSes consider creating another partition (NTFS) just for that. Doing otherwise the chance of your Windows **not booting** afterwards is very high.

Comment: Good answer, could you please add information how to disable fastboot?

Comment: Please Notice it I am having access to those NTFS drives in Ubuntu too before updating. but now (After Update) it is giving Such type of Error.  And I just bring it in your notice that I have rebooted my system before it many times with both OS and did not get this Error before now.

Comment: @Michal - Done! ;-)

Comment: @AbhishekTandon perhaps previous versions never checked if Windows was hibernated and allowed you access which could cause damage. If so then in 16.04 extra protection has been added which is an improvement. Either way your screen clearly shows Windows is hibernated and that is preventing you from accessing data today.

Comment: @Abhishek Tandon - Please, first of all, consider NOT doing it for the reasons I mentioned. Please read the link I just edited in the answer for more informations about Windows 10.

Comment: @CelticWarrior -  I have followed what you changed above in your answer. And I changed Battery setting in Windows 10. But there is no solution to my problem. Still it is displaying same Error message. :(

Comment: Two options then: 1. You didn' t follow the steps (most likley) or 2. Your Windows drive is in an unsafe state and needs correction. You can use the error correction tool in Windows to check and correct it. Make sure you reboot to Windows to allow the tool to do its job.

Comment: I have followed both options above in your answer and then restarted with windows, again shut down it and rebooted with Ubuntu.

Comment: can you elaborate when you said drive is in unsafe state ? How can I check drive state and what should I do in that case ?

Comment: There's something you are really not understanding... First of all, if "options" are mentioned then you use one or the other, not both. Option 1 is GUI based whereas option 2 is simple registry editing (option 1 is recommended, obviously). Again, after applying the settings change you MUST shutdown, not reboot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44913/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-abhishek-tandon).